# Model for log-inear data

Tags: plotting, fitting

I am trying to fit the following data with y axis on a log scale. I used the following model to fit the data but without success.

Can anyone help me suggest a proper model?

```
data = {{0.8000, 100000000.00}, {0.8028, 82008960.54}, {0.8028, 
    88704567.22}, {0.8028, 95569262.75}, {0.8065, 
    74930994.80}, {0.8074, 69005245.31}, {0.8112, 
    63795934.75}, {0.8130, 60149303.92}, {0.8148, 
    55175111.15}, {0.8176, 51210865.13}, {0.8194, 
    47345844.06}, {0.8231, 42586090.69}, {0.8268, 
    38154882.10}, {0.8296, 34589763.45}, {0.8324, 
    32230723.75}, {0.8379, 28876433.27}, {0.8407, 
    26178274.99}, {0.8482, 24011931.03}, {0.8500, 
    21768524.26}, {0.8546, 19811674.52}, {0.8583, 
    18316061.18}, {0.8648, 16474214.72}, {0.8685, 
    15170924.72}, {0.8741, 13807015.89}, {0.8825, 
    12664307.93}, {0.8843, 11662660.74}, {0.8908, 
    10824275.54}, {0.8974, 10125283.11}, {0.9001, 
    9143260.25}, {0.9076, 8485898.89}, {0.9160, 7875718.77}, {0.9187, 
    7367433.69}, {0.9262, 6837746.68}, {0.9308, 6346335.88}, {0.9392, 
    5959723.49}, {0.9467, 5596720.15}, {0.9523, 5214861.55}, {0.9597, 
    4820987.27}, {0.9690, 4319085.26}, {0.9783, 4071870.70}, {0.9821, 
    3764479.01}, {0.9942, 3521167.36}, {0.9998, 3293816.71}, {1.0053, 
    3069082.90}, {1.0128, 2904846.86}, {1.0203, 2760205.60}, {1.0287, 
    2571800.93}, {1.0361, 2424646.34}, {1.0473, 2206528.92}, {1.0585, 
    2008033.00}, {1.0697, 1863588.05}, {1.0809, 1729533.55}, {1.0920, 
    1567785.50}, {1.0995, 1478079.16}, {1.1126, 1393420.50}, {1.1191, 
    1313704.45}, {1.1265, 1248291.07}, {1.1377, 1144943.95}, {1.1508, 
    1083608.24}, {1.1592, 1009643.88}, {1.1676, 944425.49}, {1.1797, 
    886855.90}, {1.1928, 813415.74}, {1.2002, 785136.28}, {1.2123, 
    722957.14}, {1.2217, 681576.73}, {1.2319, 642558.29}, {1.2413, 
    615359.64}, {1.2497, 584713.04}, {1.2590, 555587.06}, {1.2702, 
    523775.85}, {1.2786, 493801.15}, {1.2907, 458275.61}, {1.3000, 
    437159.24}, {1.3084, 408920.75}, {1.3178, 390078.54}, {1.3290, 
    370640.22}, {1.3401, 343978.75}, {1.3551, 317972.40}, {1.3644, 
    302133.42}, {1.3747, 282611.22}, {1.3849, 264350.44}, {1.3989, 
    248231.30}, {1.4120, 233097.43}, {1.4213, 217184.57}, {1.4316, 
    203151.30}, {1.4465, 191511.68}, {1.4521, 180557.35}, {1.4624, 
    172912.83}, {1.4736, 162374.19}, {1.4838, 151882.47}, {1.4931, 
    145453.48}, {1.5043, 134990.50}, {1.5183, 126759.26}, {1.5258, 
    119038.43}, {1.5379, 113996.20}, {1.5445, 108746.82}, {1.5519, 
    104145.83}, {1.5613, 98958.08}, {1.5715, 94397.34}, {1.5808, 
    88645.84}, {1.5911, 84560.37}, {1.6004, 80348.21}, {1.6135, 
    75154.25}, {1.6266, 69746.72}, {1.6378, 66271.11}, {1.6462, 
    61990.30}, {1.6564, 58901.81}, {1.6667, 55529.84}, {1.6779, 
    52145.43}, {1.6881, 48776.08}, {1.6975, 46346.42}, {1.7087, 
    43692.77}, {1.7208, 40708.75}, {1.7311, 38832.58}, {1.7385, 
    36754.53}, {1.7469, 34787.33}, {1.7553, 33446.11}, {1.7628, 
    32156.92}, {1.7702, 30675.82}, {1.7796, 29033.67}, {1.7852, 
    27915.14}, {1.7936, 27050.26}, {1.8020, 26007.33}, {1.8085, 
    24907.24}, {1.8206, 23480.89}, {1.8299, 22311.25}, {1.8430, 
    20868.98}, {1.8542, 19674.09}, {1.8645, 18402.86}, {1.8766, 
    17417.18}, {1.8869, 16420.09}, {1.8999, 15178.96}, {1.9120, 
    14253.70}, {1.9214, 13385.24}, {1.9316, 12718.36}, {1.9438, 
    11849.75}, {1.9624, 10740.67}, {1.9811, 9659.32}, {1.9969, 
    8824.48}, {2.0137, 8125.21}, {2.0305, 7278.72}, {2.0483, 
    6728.21}, {2.0623, 6122.76}, {2.0762, 5704.49}, {2.0902, 
    5232.05}, {2.1052, 4855.49}, {2.1173, 4523.89}, {2.1285, 
    4298.45}, {2.1527, 3702.21}, {2.1807, 3188.55}, {2.2031, 
    2811.72}, {2.2293, 2421.66}, {2.2554, 2069.41}, {2.2796, 
    1839.18}, {2.2983, 1647.54}, {2.3151, 1511.05}, {2.3281, 
    1385.92}, {2.3505, 1261.09}, {2.3729, 1120.81}, {2.4000, 
    1000.00}}
```

```
ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> False]
```

Can anyone help me to model the above data?

Comment: You want to fit it or plot it or both?

Comment: Try `ListLogLogPlot`. The trend is fairly linear if you don't care about a slight wobble.

Answer (score 1):

> Actually I am trying to fit an equation using FindFit[data,model,{a,b,c,....},x]. I tried exponential, polynomial etc, but no equation fits properly to the above data. Can anyone suggest a model to fit the equation.

This can be done using Quantile Regression. The answer below uses the [QRMon package](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/).

Load the `QRMon` package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]
```

Rescale the data:

```
data2 = Map[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} &, data];
```

Do a quantile regression fit and plot data, regression functions, and relative errors:

```
obj2 =
  QRMonUnit[data2] ⟹
   QRMonSetRegressionFunctionsPlotOptions[{PlotStyle -> Red}] ⟹
   QRMonQuantileRegression[8, 0.5] ⟹
   QRMonPlot[PlotRange -> All] ⟹
   QRMonErrorPlots;
```

[image]

Get the regression function from the monad object and show symbolic, simplified version of it:

```
qFunc2 = (obj2 ⟹ QRMonTakeRegressionFunctions)[0.5];
PiecewiseExpand[qFunc2[x]]
```

[image]

Define a function that rescales to the original co-domain:

```
qFunc = Exp@*qFunc2;
```

Plot the original data and the fitted function (with log-plots):

```
Show[{
  ListLogPlot[data, PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[0.65], 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> Large], 
  ListLogPlot[{#, qFunc[#]} & /@ data[[All, 1]], 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

### First answer (made for clarification purposes)

It seems you get a reasonable result with `ListLogPlot`:

```
ListLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anton.  Actually  I am trying to fit an equation using FindFit[data,model,{a,b,c,....},x].  I tried exponential, polynomial etc, but no equation fits properly to the above data.  Can anyone suggest a model to fit the equation.